# How to reinstall android on my HTC

Tags: recovery-mode, custom-roms, rom

I have encrypted my HTC One M7 and then entered a wrong password until destruction of data. How can I recover my HTC.

In other words, how do I reinstall Android 6.0 on it?

I tried "power button + volume lower" and then **factory reset**. It leads to **TWRP**.

PS: I am using Linux, and have no Windows machine available

[image]

Comment: If you can enter to fastboot mode you will try to flash an image.

Comment: If you are using TWRP, can you not just perform a factory reset there? Wipe caches, data, and internal storage? Otherwise, you would need to find the official RUU file and run it on a Windows computer (it doesn't work in Linux) to restore it to factory settings.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to factory reset from twrp even if you can't decrypt it. On the flip side, I know HTC devices have RUU's wich allow to install factory images etc.